# How does a microwave oven-leakage detector work?

Tags: sensor, rf, microwave, radiation

What type of sensor or circuitry is inside one of these devices that allows measurement of microwave radiation strength? I've never opened one but I'm assuming it's similar to measuring RSSI on a wireless receiver module, e.g. an Xbee.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing like that fancy. The power levels are very high in comparison to a receiver. It's simply an antenna, an RF diode and an RC to filter the DC.

Of course they may wish to stick some microcontroller with an LCD display on there, but that's just working with the DC voltage from the front-end "crystal set".